# Ubuntu best practices in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2

Can have someone help me on how to secure the ubuntu ec2 instance in AWS?

Comment: Well. it comes down to this - what have you tried that doesn't work? See how to ask a good question here: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that AWS provides the security groups.
with the help of that security groups you can open particular ports.